# Smallest Graph that is Regular but not Vertex-Transitive?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, examples-counterexamples, abstract-algebra

I'm trying to find the smallest graph that is regular but not vertex-transitive, where by smallest I mean "least number of vertices", and if two graphs have the same number of vertices, then the smaller is the one with the lower number of edges.

I currently have that the smallest such graph is the disjoint union of the three-cycle and the four-cycle.

Are there any smaller graphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that a graph is vertex transitive if and only if its complement is, and a regular graph on at most six vertices is the complement of a regular graph with valency at most two. It is easy to write down all graphs with valency at most two on at most six vertices.

Comment: Is that easy? There are many graphs on at most six vertices. Even to eliminate all the ones with valency $> 2$ would still leave me checking on the order of $2^{15}$ graphs. Is there a particular technique you have in mind?

Comment: You only want regular graphs on at most six vertices with max valency two. There are not very many. If these are all vertex transitive, then all regular graphs with at most six vertices are vertex transitive.

Comment: Okay, I sketched it out. The regular graphs on $n$ vertices with valency $2$ are all just cycles, which are vertex-transitive. Is that correct? This leads me to believe that I've found the minimal example (seeing as a regular graph on 7 vertices with fewer than 7 edges is not possible).

Comment: @Newb Yes. A regular graph with valency $0$ is trivially transitive. Regular with valency $1$ is always vertex transitive (it's just a bunch of isolated edges). Regular with valency $2$ means we have disjoint cycles; as each must have length $\ge3$, to even have more than one cycle (which is always transitive) we need $n\ge 6$; with $n=6$ we could have two $3$-cycles, still transitive; with $n=7$, we have your example.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen As I thought. Thanks for making it clear!

Comment: The argument given in the answer can be used to show that the union of a 3-cycle and a 4-cycle and the complement of this graph are the only graphs on 7 vertices that are regular but not vertex-transitive.  For there is no 1-regular graph on 7 vertices (since 7 is odd), there are only two 2-regular graphs on 7 vertices (the 7-cycle and the union of 3- and 4-cycles), and there are no 3-regular graphs on 7 vertices (by the handshaking lemma). These are the two smallest counterexamples since (by the same argument) all regular graphs on 6 or fewer vertices are vertex-transitive.